# can't show google map polygon when set javascript variable from json

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I need to show the polygon in the web page. The color of the area must be changing dynamically depending on the count of residents in this area. The number of residents is stored in the json file. If I put a constant count of residents the polygon is drawn, but when I call the json file and set count from json polygon is not drawn. Please help! this is my code:

```
function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {lat: 43.2392374, lng: 76.8871528},
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    });
    var json = require('./data.json');
    var jobj = json["1"];
    var colAlma = parseInt(jobj["cnt"]);

    var almaCoords = [
        { lat: 43.256389, lng: 76.865019 },
        { lat: 43.233377, lng: 76.870684 },
        { lat: 43.237147, lng: 76.877402 },
        { lat: 43.238709, lng: 76.889548 },
        { lat: 43.242597, lng: 76.948407 },
        { lat: 43.270325, lng: 76.944681 },
        { lat: 43.268801, lng: 76.923655 },
        { lat: 43.265717, lng: 76.909109 },
        { lat: 43.265011, lng: 76.904823 },
        { lat: 43.257689, lng: 76.883541 },
        { lat: 43.258172, lng: 76.870425 }
    ];

    var colorAlma ;

    if (colAlma > 0 && colAlma < 10){
        colorAlma = '#00FF7F';
    }
    if (colAlma >= 10 && colAlma < 20){
        colorAlma = '#00FF00';
    }
    if (colAlma >= 20 && colAlma < 30){
        colorAlma = '#ADFF2F';
    }
    if (colAlma >= 30 && colAlma < 40){
        colorAlma = '#EEE8AA';
    }
    if (colAlma >= 40 && colAlma < 50){
        colorAlma = '#FFD700';
    }
    if (colAlma >= 50 && colAlma < 60){
        colorAlma = '#FF8C00';
    }
    if (colAlma >= 60 && colAlma < 70){
        colorAlma = '#FF4500';
    }   

    var almaTriangle = new google.maps.Polygon({
        paths: almaCoords,
        strokeColor: colorAlma,
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: colorAlma,
        fillOpacity: 0.35
    });
    almaTriangle.setMap(map);
}
```

Comment: provide json file sample data & is there any key "cnt" in json object ?? cos you used jobj["cnt"]

Comment: Yes, this is my json:   {
 "0":{"cnt":"5"},
 "1":{"cnt":"65"},
 "2":{"cnt":"4"}
}

Comment: what is your console.log(json) outputting ? or any console error ?

Comment: This code is in html file, but when check it in js file, there is no error. console show me  { "0":{"cnt":"5"}, "1":{"cnt":"65"}, "2":{"cnt":"4"} }

Comment: Sorry , it seems everything is correct and working at my end

Comment: Thanks, i found solution. I change the colAlma from javaFX webEngine. webEngine.executeScript("window.colAlma = " + cntAlma+ ";");